# Remove special symbols from email string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, python-re

I need to replace some characters in email string, exactly such actions:

```
lower_email = str.lower(str.split(email,'@')[0])
nopunc_email = re.sub('[!@#$%^&*()-=+.,]', ' ', lower_email)
nonum_email = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', nopunc_email).strip()
```

**But in SQL**

I tried to use expression `TRANSLATE(lower(email), 'a1_a.a-a@1-+()a ', 'a a a a')`, but it didn't give me solution.

Thanks in advance!

For example:

```
import re
email = 'some_email.example-2021@gmail.com'
lower_email = str.lower(str.split(email,'@')[0])
nopunc_email = re.sub('[!@_#$%^&*()-=+.,]', ' ', lower_email)
nonum_email = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', nopunc_email).strip()

result 'some email example'
```

Comment: Привет! Can you please provide us with a desired result at least?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot, but how about `replace(translate(email,'!#$%^&*()=+','?'),'?')`?

Comment: provided the desired result in description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT email,
       TRIM(
         TRANSLATE(
           LOWER(SUBSTR(email, 1, INSTR(email, '@') - 1)),
           '!_#$%^&*()-=+.,0123456789',
           '               '
         )
       ) AS translated
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (email) AS
SELECT 'some_email.example-2021@gmail.com' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMAIL | TRANSLATED |
> | --- | --- |
> | some_email.example-2021@gmail.com | some email example |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e48160cde6e86d970e1738c8d2002728)*

Comment: Thank you very much! Additional question, how may I "split" string by character to get its tokens (in pl/sql)? like python str.split(email,'@')

Comment: @ЛюбовьПономарева Use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` as in the answer. `SUBSTR(email, 1, INSTR(email, '@') - 1)` gets the substring before the `@` and `SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1)` gets the substring after the `@`.

Comment: but when I has multiple @?

Comment: @ЛюбовьПономарева Use `INSTR` to find the position of the `@`s and get the substring between them.